# Does this armor set work RAW?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, optimization, armor

[Haramaki](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/armor/haramaki) is a [light armor](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/armor/eastern-armor-and-shields#TOC-Haramaki) that gives +1 ac at 0 % casting failure chance. Same thing works with [Ceremonial silk armor](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/armor/silken-ceremonial-armor), but it's heavier and costs more. -- now if you combine that with an [armored kilt](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/armor#TOC-Amrored-kilt), then the set counts as medium armor, thus it [may or may not](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/28347/does-the-armor-category-inherently-imply-a-speed-change) slow you down. After spending 21 gp (or 50 gp for silk), you now have +2 AC with up to +6 dex bonus, and 0 % spell failure and 0 Armor penalty - so even if you're not proficient with any armors, this seems to works, RAW that is. Does it?

Bonus, could this be worn at the same time as or integrated with [mock armor](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateEquipment/gear/adventuringGear.html)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does the Armored Kilt work?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/28270/how-does-the-armored-kilt-work)

Comment: related: [wearing-armor-without-proficiency](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/16604/3358)

Answer (score 6):

According to RAW, yes, I see no reason why you couldn't combine an armored kilt with a haramaki. You might want to get a mithril buckler with that too.

I'm not sure about the mock armor. Can you wear it over armor? It doesn't say. I suppose some GMs might allow it, others won't.

But that's true for anything of course; the GM can always ban it, and I imagine particularly the armored kilt is a good candidate for that.

Comment: Why would the armored kilt be particularly good ban bait? Certainly not for the risk of a +2 armor bonus on a mage, Mage Armor gives twice that much with no penalty or arcane failure or even weight to carry or sunder/take-away-gear vulnerability, all for the cost of one spell slot available to anyone who would care about both no prof needed and no arcane failure.

Comment: Because it's a very cheap way to stack obscure AC bonuses. I suppose it slowing you down as medium armour is a fair trade-off, though that means that any dwarf will usually add an armoured kilt to whatever armour he's wearing. With such a unique and very useful effect, it should be incredibly common. It's not just useful to wizards, it's useful to almost anyone. It's not game breaking, but as a GM, I feel it smells a bit. Of all the non-magical armours in the game, it seems to me to be among the easiest to abuse, and the most likely to be banned.

Comment: Except it's still only +1 AC. It's not just non-game-breaking, it's negligible outside of a few edge cases. The only real cheese potential is if you rule that the kilt can be separately enchanted, and all the enchantment apply at once, which is a lot easier (and, I would argue, the best-fit interpretation of the ambiguous RAW) to simply rule that you can enchant either your kilt or your regular armor, but if you enchant both, they won't work, the same as wearing 2 magic rings on one hand, and they don't work.